# system.threading.timer can not worked

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have used the `System.Threading.Timer` in windows service when i have set the timer to execute after 1 min. starting from 12:00:00.

```
 timer1[timer] = 
     new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate, obj, dueTime, interval);
```

timer excuted at this interval

> 12:00:00
>   12:00:59
>   12:01:00
>   12:02:00
>   12:02:59

but i want to excute at

> 12:00:00
>   12:01:00
>   12:02:00
>   12:03:00

why timer started at 12:00:59?

i have set the remainder for execution following code

declaration:

```
_interval[timer] = interval;
_startTime[timer] = DATeTime + dueTime;
```

used in timer callback method

```
long elapsedMs = Convert.ToInt64((dt - _startTime[timer]).TotalMilliseconds);
long intervalMs = Convert.ToInt64(_interval[timer].TotalMilliseconds);
long remainder = elapsedMs % intervalMs;
if (remainder != 0L)
{
    timer1[timer].Change(
        _interval[timer] - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(remainder), 
        _interval[timer]);
}
```

When used the same application in windows XP it's woking perfectly but in windows 7 & windows server 2008 it is not working.

How to resolve this problem in `Threading.Timer`?

Comment: The short answer is: don't use `Threading.Timer`. It is not accurate. You'll need to use a high-resolution multimedia timer. See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework) for example.

Comment: its working in windows XP perfectly why not in windows 7

Comment: Maybe the Win7 machine is busy, while the WinXP is more idle. A good check would be to overload your WinXP machine with lots of processes and see if your solution still works. With multimedia timers it will.

Comment: This is a display artifact.  DateTime.ToString() truncates, it doesn't round.  So if you start 1 millisecond before 12:00 then you'll see an occasional :59.  Not a real problem of course.  Print the full time, including milliseconds to convince yourself.

Comment: The OP problem is that the timer seems to have fired twice at ~12:01.  There may well be display artifacts and/or rounding/truncing errors and/or different loading on different machines/OS, but none of that explains: '12:00:59 12:01:00'

Comment: The code you've posted is obscure and clearly incomplete, so it's pretty hard to diagnose the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try System.Timers.Timer - it has worked well for me. For convenience, I pasted a static timer class with a delegate:

```
public static class Timer 
    {
        private static System.Timers.Timer _timer =  new System.Timers.Timer();
        public static void start(bool enabled, int interval)
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(); 
            _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timerElapsed);
            _timer.Enabled = enabled;
            _timer.Interval = interval;
        }
        static void _timerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            OnTimedEvent(sender, e);                
        }
    }
```

Comment: `System.Timers.Timer` uses `System.Threading.Timer` internally, so I don't think it will solve any problems the OP had.

Comment: Why this work only on local test? When I deploy to porduction server, this do nothing, its happens it yours?